# Validating Final Form Array on Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form, final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I am building an application with React Final Form. In the form, user needs to fill up basic input fields as well as add questions with its choices. For the questions and choices I am using `FieldArray` feature. So, until here everything is good and working. However, I would like to add another functionality to this form.

As you can see in the image below, this is a Card component rendered inside `FieldArray`. Every time user clicks *Add a Question* button, There will be another Card component on the page.

The feature I need is to make the `Save` button work on top-right corner. At the moment I don't know how should I implement the Save button but what I wanna achieve is that I want to toggle the Card component in the image to another Card component, where I display the input data by using `fields.value`. So, no input field. However, I want to also validate this portion of the form when I click save. This is what I don't know how to do. So, every Save button will validate its own fields and if validation passes, the Card will be toggled to another Card component where the data is read-only.

So, I need your suggestion for the validation part as well as your opinion to add this functionality.

Thanks

[image]

**Edit**

I've been reading the docs of FinalForm as well as ReduxForm to figure out how can I handle this situation but I couldn't figure it out yet.

I've checked the Wizard example in FinalForm docs. However I am not sure if it's suitable for my situation. Wizard has a single `<form>` tag present at all times on a page and when a user clicks next button, input fields switch. In my case, I might need multiple form tags as you mentioned.

I've put 3 form structures as an example. Can you tell me which way is to go?

`import { Form as FinalForm } from 'react-final-form'`

### #1 Basic Form:

Classic way of structuring the form and it is the current situation. So, this is not the way to solve the issue.

```js
      <FinalForm onSubmit={aCustomSubmitFunction}>
        {
          ({ handleSubmit }) => {
            return (
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Field name='firstName'>{({input}) => <input {...input} />}</Field>
                <Field name='lastName'>{({input}) => <input {...input} />}</Field>
                <FieldArray name='questions'>
                  {({ fields }) => (
                    <div>
                      {fields.map((name, index) => {
                        return (
                          <div className="card">
                            <Field name={`${name}.question`}>{({input}) => <input {...input} type="text" />}</Field>
                            <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>Delete</button>
                            <button type="submit">Save</button>
                          </div>
                        )
                      })}
                      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({ question: undefined })}>Add a Question</button>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </FieldArray>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </form>
            )
          }
        }
      </FinalForm>
```

### #2 Multiple forms under a single FinalForm:

Multiple forms inside a FinalForm. This seems to be the way to go, however 'save' button submits the entire form not its own form. It is using the same `handleSubmit` so this must be the reason, though how can I have a different handleSubmit? Wrapping the form tag that is inside FieldArray with another `FinalForm`?

```js
      <FinalForm onSubmit={aCustomSubmitFunction}>
        {
          ({ handleSubmit }) => {
            return (
              <>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <Field name='firstName'>{({input}) => <input {...input} />}</Field>
                  <Field name='lastName'>{({input}) => <input {...input} />}</Field>
                  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <FieldArray name='questions'>
                  {({ fields }) => (
                    <div>
                      {fields.map((name, index) => {
                        return (
                          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <div className="card">
                              <Field name={`${name}.question`}>{({input}) => <input {...input} type="text" />}</Field>
                              <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>Delete</button>
                              <button type="submit">Save</button>
                            </div>
                          </form>
                        )
                      })}
                      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({ question: undefined })}>Add a Question</button>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </FieldArray>
              </>
            )
          }
        }
      </FinalForm>
```

### #3 Multiple nested forms under a single FinalForm:

This is invalid html. So this must be wrong approach but while I was doing a research I found a thing called React Portals, which might be helpful but I think it's unnecessary.

```js
      <FinalForm onSubmit={aCustomSubmitFunction}>
        {
          ({ handleSubmit }) => {
            return (
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Field name='firstName'>{({input}) => <input {...input} />}</Field>
                <Field name='lastName'>{({input}) => <input {...input} />}</Field>
                <FieldArray name='questions'>
                  {({ fields }) => (
                    <div>
                      {fields.map((name, index) => {
                        return (
                          <form>
                            <div className="card">
                              <Field name={`${name}.question`}>{({input}) => <input {...input} type="text" />}</Field>
                              <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>Delete</button>
                              <button type="submit">Save</button>
                            </div>
                          </form>
                        )
                      })}
                      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({ question: undefined })}>Add a Question</button>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </FieldArray>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </form>
            )
          }
        }
      </FinalForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate only part of a form, you must split it into multiple forms, and have the "Save" button "submit" the form. The [Wizard Example](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/wizard) does this, collecting the form values from each "page" in a parent component.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Erik, thank you for your quick response as well as your work for redux form and final form. I appreciate it so much. Unfortunately I couldn't figure it out. However, I updated the image in the question to give a better representation of how the form looks like. Also added some to get your opinion. Thanks.

Comment: You should only ever have one `<form/>` inside a `<FinalForm/>`. You can have multiple `<FinalForm/>`s on the page, though, each with its own validation rules for the fields it contains. How you manage what happens with the values on submit is up to you.